# I am trying to solve the problem in C++ Files and Streams

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class Model
```

{

```
public:
  Model(const char *a)
{
  message=a;
}
const char *car() { return message; }
const char *message;

};
class ModelCar
{
public:
ModelCar(const char *sn, const char *b="c")
{
 filename=strdup(sn);
 f=fopen(sn,b);
 if (f==NULL)
{
throw Model("File can't be opened");
}

}
~ModelCar()
{
  delete [] filename;
  if (fclose(f)<0)
{
  throw Model("File can't be closed");
}
}
void read(char *buf, int size)
{
 if (fread(buf, 1, size, f)!=size)
{
 throw Model("File can't be read");
}

}
 const char *filename;
 FILE *f;
};
```

Why I am getting error: ‘strdup’ was not declared in this scope , I tried and add #include <string.h> but still getting error
Can anyone please help me what is wrong in this code

Comment: Could you please indent your code.

Comment: That code is unreadable.....

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to fix some problems with the code:
1.

```
delete [] filename;
filename=strdup(sn);
```

Okay your delete function suggests that your filename is a dynamic array which you never intialized. Also have you looked at what strdup returns, it returns a dynamic char, not an dynamic array. I would suggest you change:

```
delete [] filename;
```

to

```
free(filename);
```